# sql which is better to insert row if not exist before

Tags: php, mysql, sql, insert

I am currently using the following method to insert a row in a table when a column does not exist.. otherwise i generate new column id and try again

```
    $item_id = $this->misc_model->generateId(18);

    while ($flag == false){

        $this->db->where('item_id', $item_id);
        $sql = $this->db->get($this->db->dbprefix('table'));

        if ($sql->num_rows()){
            $item_id = $this->misc_model->generateId(18);
        }else{
            $flag = true;
        }
    }
```

can this be done faster this way?

```
 IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM table WHERE item_id = $item_id)
    INSERT INTO table (item_id) VALUES ($item_id)
```

Comment: Perhaps create a unique index on `item_id` and try to insert until you succeed... in theory this might take forever and is not very efficient but i think the method above is prone to race conditions...

Answer (score 2):

If item_id is your primary key then you're much better off using an [AUTO INCREMENT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/example-auto-increment.html) and letting the db handle this for you.

Comment: item_id is generated by the function generateId()... table also has a column (id) which is AUTO_INCREMENT

Comment: @fxuser Ok, you may need to explain your intention in a bit more detail. It sounds like you are trying to create another unique identifier for each row. That's a bit pointless. What is item_id and what does it represent?

Comment: item_id is a unique id created for each row except id(auto_increment) its actually a random 18 length integer

Comment: it seems i dont need the item_id column and only id that is auto_increment can do the job as well.. so what i do with the while loop is not needed right?

Comment: @fxuser If you don't need the item_id then just insert the row and get the auto increment and use that. Should be no need for your other code.

Answer (score 1):

if you are good to go with a new item_id always then you can try this in your insert statement

```
INSERT INTO table_name (item_id) value (RIGHT(CONCAT(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(),UNIX_TIMESTAMP()),18))
```

this will always generate new item_id for you

Answer (score 0):

you should have your columns as auto increment, but if for some reason you cant, that would be faster, yes!